# Reputed Magical Effects of Real-World Herbs

Tags: magic

For various reasons I want to go back to primary sources to develop a list of herb and their magic effects for various fantasy RPGs that I use to run my campaign, the Majestic Wilderlands.

Does anybody know of a good reference, online or book, to a list of real world herbs and their reputed magical effects?

Comment: Would an herbal guide help if it was just the real-world uses? You might be able to extend it.

Comment: There is a list of herbs and their reputed *non*-magical uses in an appendix of the AD&D 1e DMG. Useful for some inspiration, but too focused on mundanely folk-remedy uses to give much guidance for the sort of magical uses I'd want in a fantasy game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a supplement for Ars Magica, [Hedge Magic](http://www.rpg.net/news+reviews/reviews/rev_2766.html) (by Atlas Games, ISBN 1-887801-58-8), that lists herbs (and stones) that have magical properties based on historical beliefs. (Does anyone have access to this book? Is there a bibliography?)

And, while searching for that link, I found [Medicinal and Magical Herbs of Medieval Europe](https://web.archive.org/web/20150617080929/http://www.quantal.demon.co.uk/saga/ooc/herbs.html) list, too!

Answer (score 7):

There was an RPG-centric series of columns about plants on RPG.net a few years back. It was called *[The Vegetative State of your Game](http://www.rpg.net/columns/list-column.phtml?colname=vegetative)*.

It's got all sorts of information on plants in use by different cultures - in war, in healing, as drugs, as valuable spices, etc. The columns with the most emphasis on magic are:

- [Plants in Folklore and Legend, Part One: Trees](http://www.rpg.net/columns/vegetative/vegetative7.phtml)
- [Plants in Folklore and Legend, Part Two: Mystic Plants of Damage and Doom](http://www.rpg.net/columns/vegetative/vegetative8.phtml)!
- [Plants of Goodness](http://www.rpg.net/columns/vegetative/vegetative9.phtml)

But there are 21 more chock full of information.

I still refer to those columns today. I guess that's obvious...

Answer (score 4):

[Hildegard von Bingen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hildegard_von_Bingen) wrote "Physica" and "Causae et Curae", both of which might be worth a look.

Hildegard von Bingen was a famous herbalist of the 12th century. Both books mentioned above are treatises on human health and illness, and the cures to be found in herbs, animals, minerals etc.; "Physica" is generally considered a milestone in western herbalism. They're Latin, however; you might fare better with a translation or secondary source.

Answer (score 4):

One of my players once linked me [this list of real herbs from Oblivion](http://oblivion.melian.cc/?cmd=cmdOblivionIngredientList) and their uses in that game. They're not real world effects, but I've found it useful and have stolen lots of names from it.

Answer (score 3):

In the realm of real-world source material, you can always find stuff from neopagan sources. [Cunningham's Encyclopedia of Magical Herb](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0875421229)s certainly fits the bill for what you're looking for. It contains references on 400 herbs, and their modern / historical magical uses along with an annotated bibliography at the back of the book with even more primary sources.